# How to have a different style for edges of a triangle

Tags: graphics

Consider the following triangle.

`Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Red]], Gray, Triangle[]}]`

The `EdgeForm` is defining the edges style for all three edges of the triangle.

How can I give separate `Directive` for each edge of the `Triangle`.

Comment: By using `Line` for each edge of the triangle separately.

Comment: You mean have three separate `Line` objects that connect to give an illusion of a `Triangle`?

Comment: Yes. And in order to obtain a filled triangle, you may use a true `Triangle` object with specified `FaceForm` and `EdgeForm[None]`; the `Line` objects have to appear in the list _afterwards_ (so that the `Line` objects are plotted _after_ the `Triangle` object).

Answer (score 8):

You can construct lines from the input `Triangle` and add them to your list of primitives in `Graphics`:

```
ClearAll[triangleToLines]
triangleToLines[Triangle[a_]] := Line /@ Partition[Append[a, a[[1]]], 2, 1]
```

**Examples:**

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick]], Gray, Triangle[], 
  Opacity[.5], CapForm["Round"], Thickness[.05], 
  Thread[{{Red, Green, Blue}, triangleToLines[Triangle[]] }]}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick]], Gray, Triangle[],
  Opacity[.5], CapForm["Round"], Thickness[.05], 
  MapThread[# /. Line[x_] :> Line[x, VertexColors -> #2] &, {triangleToLines[
     Triangle[]] , Partition[{Red, Green, Blue}, 2, 1, 1]}]}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick]], Gray, Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}}], 
  Opacity[.5], CapForm["Round"], Thickness[.05], 
  Thread[{{Red, Green, Blue}, triangleToLines[Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}}]] }]}]
```

[image]

```
t3d = Triangle[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}]; 
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick]], Gray, t3d, 
  Opacity[.5], CapForm["Round"], Thickness[.05], 
  Thread[{{Red, Green, Blue}, Tube[#, .1] & @@@ triangleToLines[t3d] }]}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 The definition for `triangleToLines[Triangle[]]` is unnecessary. It is handled by the general case.

Comment: Thank you @BobHanlon. Excellent point!!